# How can I concatenate rows of a column in a matrix using another column as criteria

Tags: java, arrays

Supose a I have the following array:

```
String[ ] array = new String {
    { a2,  a4,  a5,  a1,  a3 },
    {5.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 2.0 }
};
```

Arranged as a 5X2 matrix:

(a2;      2.0)

(a4;      2.0)

(a5;      2.0)

(a1;      5.0)

(a3;      5.0)

I wish to concatenate the rows of the first column using as criteria the values in second one, generating the following 2X2 matrix:

("a2, a4, a5"; 2.0)

("a1, a3"; 5.0)

Thanks!

Comment: Look into `Stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...));`

Comment: Actually, you would also need to `.stream().reduce(...)` the respective values. Makes for a nice one-liner, but is really hard to properly engineer for someone without prior functional programming experience.

Comment: You can't store numbers in a string array.

Comment: Also, the type should be `String[][]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing we need to do is change your array type to `Object[][]` so it can hold both strings and numbers:

```
Object[][] array = {
    { "a2",  "a4",  "a5",  "a1",  "a3" },
    { 5.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 2.0 }
};
```

Now we use streams to produce a map of concatenated string values grouped by their corresponding numeric value, then we stream the map entries into a 2-column matrix:

```
Object[][] grouped = IntStream.range(0, array[0].length) // this will create a stream containing as many natural numbers, starting from 0, that the array has elements
        .boxed() // this will make it a stream of Integers instead of ints
        .collect(groupingBy(i -> array[1][i], mapping(i -> array[0][i].toString(), joining(", ")))) // here, we make a Map out of the stream by grouping by the i'th element of the second column in the matrix and taking as the value the respective element from the first column, then joining the resulting list of strings in the map's value with a ", " separator
        .entrySet() // now we take the entry set of the map
        .stream() // we stream it
        .map(e -> new Object[] {e.getValue(), e.getKey()}) // and we transform each entry in the map into a matrix row
        .toArray(Object[][]::new); // finally, we transform the stream of rows into a matrix (array of rows)
```

The above relies on a static import of `java.util.stream.Collectors.*`.

This can easily be adapted to work with a pure string matrix, if that's what you're after.

Comment: It's a really elegant solution, however, I really doubt someone without extensive functional programming experience could actually understand what's going on here. Upvoted anyway for the elegance, but you want want to edit it adding comments on what each line for people who aren't former Haskell gurus.

EDIT: I made an edit with the comment proposals explaining it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how the numbers you have are stored, but assuming that they are BigDecimals (for hashing reasons), use `Map<BigDecimal, StringBuilder>` to aggregate items. So, if your map already `contains()` the given decimal, `append()` to the respective `StringBuilder`, if not, create a new one. Also, as for iterating over the matrix, use a `for` loop with a shared index to iterate over the two arrays in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best/safest code (I'm making some assumptions on the array), but it will get you started.

First, fix your array:

```
String[][] array = new String[][]{{"a2","a4","a5","a1","a3"},
                                 {"5.0", "2.0", "5.0", "2.0", "2.0"}};
```

Now,

```
Map<String, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i ++) {
    map.putIfAbsent(array[1][i], new StringBuilder());
    map.get(array[1][i]).append(array[0][i]).append(" "); // Build the collected "a1, a3"  grouping by the second value;
}

String[][] result = new String[2][map.size()];
int j = 0;
for(Map.Entry<String, StringBuilder> entry : map) {
    result[j][0] = entry.getValue().toString();
    result[j][1] = entry.getKey();
}
```

I think I can do this with streams, but I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve the problem without using streams. However, like other people said, I was unsure of which were the data types to use.

```
private static final int SIZE_KEY_PLUS_CONCATENATION = 2;
private static final int INDEX_OF_KEY = 1;
private static final int INDEX_OF_VALUE = 0;
private static final String SEPARATOR = ", ";

private static final int RESULT_KEY = 0;
private static final int RESULT_VALUE = 1;
private static final String RESULT_SEPARATOR = " : ";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] matrix = new String[][]{
            {"a2", "5.0"},
            {"a4", "2.0"},
            {"a5", "5.0"},
            {"a1", "2.0"},
            {"a3", "2.0"},
    };

    String[][] result = getConcatenatedMatrix(matrix);
    for(String[] row : result) {
        System.out.println(row[RESULT_KEY] + RESULT_SEPARATOR + row[RESULT_VALUE]);
    }
}

private static String[][] getConcatenatedMatrix(String[][] inputMatrix) {
    Map<String, String> map = generateMapWithConcatenatedValues(inputMatrix);
    return convertMapToMatrix(map);

}

private static Map<String, String> generateMapWithConcatenatedValues(String[][] inputMatrix) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(String[] row : inputMatrix) {
        String key = row[INDEX_OF_KEY];
        String value = row[INDEX_OF_VALUE];
        doConcatenation(key, value, map);
    }

    return map;
}

private static void doConcatenation(String key, String value, Map<String, String> map) {
    if(map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, map.get(key) + SEPARATOR + value);
    } else {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}

private static String[][] convertMapToMatrix(Map<String, String> mapToConvert) {
    int keyCount = mapToConvert.size();
    String[][] result = new String[keyCount][SIZE_KEY_PLUS_CONCATENATION];
    Set<String> keys = mapToConvert.keySet();
    int currentKey = 0;
    for(String key : keys) {
        result[currentKey][RESULT_KEY] = key;
        result[currentKey][RESULT_VALUE] = mapToConvert.get(key);
        currentKey++;
    }

    return result;
}
```